# mongodb connect by mongoskin error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I have tried below mentioned code to connect mongo db using mongoskin node module

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("localhost:27017/mydb");
db.bind('mycollection');
db.mycollection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
console.log(items)
        db.close();
});
```

I am getting below mentioned error.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/url_parser.js:15
    throw Error("URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbnam
          ^
Error: URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at exports.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/url_parser.js:15:11)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:164:16)
    at SkinClass.SkinDb._open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/db.js:36:25)
    at SkinClass.open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:162:14)
    at SkinClass.SkinCollection._open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/collection.js:49:17)
    at SkinClass.open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:162:14)
    at SkinClass.SkinCursor._open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/cursor.js:28:25)
    at SkinClass.open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:162:14)
    at SkinClass.(anonymous function) [as toArray] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:116:14)
```

In that error it has mentioned enter username and password.I dont have username and pasword.What i have to enter for that please help me.

- My mongodb version is v1.8.2,
- node version is v0.10.28,
- mongoskin version is v1.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
 throw Error("URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbnam")
```

Have you tried adding the protocol? (i.e.:)

```
    var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb");
```

Comment: I have tried that this also it returns error `[MongoError: not master or secondary, can't read] name: 'MongoError'`

Comment: Is your mongod running?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the error itself :

```
throw Error("URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbnam
      ^
Error: URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname
```

In case you didn't understand , kindly do as mentioned below :

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb");
db.bind('mycollection');
db.mycollection.find().toArray(function(err, items) 
{
    console.log(items)
    db.close();
});
```